# Americans/Americans'/American mistrust in the world?

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

> 1. This research shows the **Americans** mistrust in the world.
> 2. This research shows **Americans'** mistrust in the world.
> 3. This research shows the **American** mistrust in the world.

What is the difference between the meaning of the aboves? Are all correct? Related information: Chrome proof-check says mistrust is problematic in 1 and 2 but not 3.

Answer (score 1):

> This research shows the Americans mistrust in the world.

This is not grammatically correct.

> This research shows the Americans' mistrust in the world.

This says that there is a group of Americans that have been discussed earlier, and they distrust the world.

> This research shows the American mistrust in the world.

This says that mistrust in the world is a quality that Americans have.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question.

Comment: _This research shows [the Americans] [mistrust in the world]._ is perfectly grammatical.